# ShellCheck doesn't check files with .sh extension (or any custom ones)

Tags: pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I have the following in my pre-commit:

```
---
repos:
- repo: local
  hooks:
  - id: shellcheck
    name: shellcheck
    entry: shellcheck
    language: system
    types: [file, bash]
    files: \.(sh\.j2|sh)$
```

For some reason it doesn't detect e.g. `script.sh` in the top directory of my git repo, or in any sub folder. However, when I remove the `files:` line, it is able to find Bash files. But only if there is no `.sh` extension. What am I doing wrong here? In theory I wouldn't even need the `files:` line, because my scripts do have the shebang (`#!/bin/bash`). But when the `.sh` is included, it doesn't recognize those files.

The software versions:

```
rpm -qa pre-commit ShellCheck
ShellCheck-0.7.2-5.fc36.x86_64
pre-commit-2.20.0-1.fc36.noarch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [the docs](https://pre-commit.com/#filtering-files-with-types):

> `types`, `types_or`, and `files` are evaluated together with `AND` when filtering

since `types: [bash]` anded with `files: \.sh\.j2` is an empty set those files won't match

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit

Comment: Thanks! Removing `bash` from the `types` did indeed the trick. One more question though. In those examples I also see this:

```
    files: ^foo/
    types: [file, python]
```

Why include both `file` and `python`? Wouldn't just `python` be sufficient? What would be reason to include `file` as well?

Comment: `identify-cli` basically always includes `file` as a type. but when not to include it? Because without it, it seems to work fine as well. I can't really find the detailed description of when to add it and why, or not to add it and why. Much appreciated if you can clear this up, thanks!

Comment: yes `python` will also always be tagged as `file` so it's redundant (though it's difficult to show a case where `and` is particularly helpful without using symlinks or submodules)